# Positioning JQuery UI Dialog near clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function for some links

```
$(".clickable").click(function(event){
     // load dialog content...
     $("#dialog").dialog();
     return false;
   });
```

What i'd like to do is have JQuery's UI dialog display near the clicked link.
Is there any way to do this using just JQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`event.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX) and [`event.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY) properties, to get the coordinates where the `click` event was fired, and move the dialog to them:

```
$(".clickable").click(function (e) {
  // open and move the dialog
  $("#dialog").dialog('open').dialog('option', 'position',[e.clientX,e.clientY]);
  return false;
});
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/aguru).

Comment: I think I'm going to try this anyway because I need to do something like it, but the link to the example doesn't seem to display a dialog box.